# How to show the exact value in Timelion?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, time-series, kibana, timelion

Here is the mapping of my data in ElasticSearch:

```
mapping = {
    "series-map": {
      "properties": {
        "network": {"type": "string"},
        "timestamp": {"type": "date"},
        "value": {"type": "integer"},
      }
    }
  }
```

**Example of data:**

```
Network   timestamp              value
paris     2016-04-16 12:00:00     30
toulouse  2016-04-17 13:00:00     14
paris     2016-04-16 22:00:00     45
```

It has been few days I'm trying to figure out how to show the value of a network during a specific day. I have tried this Timelion expression:

```
.es(index=myindex, timefield=timestamp, q='network:paris', metric='sum:value').label('current hour')
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

It is like the expression is showing me how many lines or values I have per timestamp. It is not showing the value itself.

How to do that please? Is there any way to show the value without any aggregations like avg, sum, max ... etc ?

Thank you.

Elasticsearch version 5.1

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are after. When you say "value of a network" are you referring to the `value` field or the `network` field?

Comment: Yes I will update the question.

Comment: Ok. And what do you want to see in the graph. Give an example using the data you provided in the post.

Comment: in the graph, it says you have one record in each timestamp. It should say you have 30 as a value. Don't know how to explain. I want to plot the values directly. a graph that goes to 30 then 14 then back to 45

Comment: That Timelion expression works for me. Are you sure that on those days and at those hours you really have the value you think you do?

Comment: which version of ES did you use?

Comment: One of the 5.x version, don't remember which one exactly. But I seriously doubt that the version is the problem. Any chance you could create a gist with some complete command to create an index (with complete mappings) and test data (as REST commands)?

Comment: I could work it out finaly using version 2.3. the strings are not indexed in the 5.x versions

Comment: Your post says `Elasticsearch version 5.1`

Comment: I know. I could not do what i wanted in 5.1. so after installing 2.3 instead it worked.

Comment: You should try in 5.x. I can create a gist for you if you're willing to try this one out.

Comment: sure I would like that. What would be the right mapping so that we can have the possibility to use strings in the aggregation visualization?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/astefan/50a9c686de5334f637632b2ae4f52bf8

Comment: why there is not a field for network in the mapping?

Comment: It will be added automatically by the `_bulk` request. I was lazy to add it, knowing that ES 5 will also add the `keyword` subfield and in case the `network` you provide has more words, I would have used `network.keyword` in my Timelion expression instead of `network`.

Comment: Will try that and update you. in fact network can also be something like `word-word_Word123` will it still be considered like keyword?

Comment: In case of `word-word_Word123` you would need to use `network.keyword`

Comment: Did you manage to make it work in 5.x?